# Couldn't Autowired multiple Services in a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have two services, which i want to use in one controller. I use the @Autowired annotation and @Qualifier-s, but something does not work, maybe because there is no Contructor.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Main{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("postServiceImpl")
private PostService postService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
private UserService userService;


@ModelAttribute("post")
public PostDTO userRegistrationDto() {
    return new PostDTO();
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String root(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("list", postService.listAllPosts());
    return "index";}

@GetMapping("/adminPage")
public  String admin(Model model){

???
    model.addAttribute("posts", postService.listAllPosts());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.listAllUsers());
    return "admin";}

}
```

Service 1:

```
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

public PostServiceImpl(PostRepository postRepository){
    this.postRepository = postRepository;
}

public PostServiceImpl(){}

}
```

Service 2:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
}
```

Is this the right way to add two service atributes in one model ?

```
model.addAttribute("posts", postService.listAllPosts());
model.addAttribute("users", userService.listAllUsers());
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the qualifier names in @Service annotations above the service classes like so :

```
@Service("userServImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Service("postServImpl")
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {
```

OR

If there is only one implementation for an Interface you could autowire like so :

```
@Autowired
private UserService userServiceImpl;

@Autowired
private PostService postServiceImpl;
```

Notice the object names are camel-case names for the specific implementation. In this case, you need not specify the qualifier name in @Service annotation.